# what does this means i = (i + 1 == count) ? 0 : i + 1;?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this line in my jQuery plugin.But i didn't understand what does this line do.Below is that plugin code.

Kindly explain me briefly.

```
(function ($) {
    $.simpleSlideShow = function (selector, settings) {
        // settings
        var config = {
            'delay': 2000,
            'fadeSpeed': 500
        };
        if (settings) { $.extend(config, settings); }

        // variables
        var obj = $(selector);
        var img = obj.children('img');
        var count = img.length;
        var i = 0;

        // show first image
        img.eq(0).show();

        // run slideshow
        setInterval(function () {
            img.eq(i).fadeOut(config.fadeSpeed);
            i = (i + 1 == count) ? 0 : i + 1;
            img.eq(i).fadeIn(config.fadeSpeed);
        }, config.delay);

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It is more common to write this as `i++; if(i===count) i=0;`, or `i=(i+1) % count;`. The first option is simple, and the second one is somewhat idiomatic.

Answer (score 6):

This is simple [*Conditional (ternary) Operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which is same as

```
if(i + 1 == count){
   i = 0;
}
else{
   i = i+1;
}
```

Just a suggestion  it could be just

```
i = (i+1) % count;
```

Comment: its proper name is the **conditional operator.** The term "ternary" is not informative.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I know that anyway updated the answer, I told that as *ternary* because that name is famous. thanx for response.

Answer (score 4):

in English, it means:
   if i+1 is equal to count, then i=0. Else, i = i+1.

It's a shorthand notation in a lot of languages.

Answer (score 2):

The `a ? b : c` syntax is a ternary operator.
This will be the same as

```
if(i + 1 == count)
   i = 0;

else
   i = i + 1;
```

See more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 2):

This is simple ternary operator as guys said already, but I would use this instead: `i = ++i % count`.

Answer (score 1):

This is short form of `if` and `else`. Meaning of this statement

```
i = (i + 1 == count) ? 0 : i + 1;
```

is same as

```
if (i + 1 == count) {
   i = 0;
} else {
   i = i+1;
}
```